# Marshalling error: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling, xmlbeans

While I was Marshalling an object I got this exception: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class Subscription nor any of its super class is known to this context.

I know there are solutions by @XmlSeeAlso and modifying jaxb classes but when we generate JAXB classes from XSD/WSDL file we cannot change them. So, those solutions will not work for this scenario.

```
  public static String getStringFromSubscription(Subscription subscription) throws MbException
  {
Marshaller marshaller;
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    try
    {
      marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.myhealth.com.ObjectFactory.class
            .getPackage().getName()).createMarshaller();
      marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
      marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration", Boolean.FALSE);
marshaller.marshal(subscription, stringWriter);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      throw new MbException(e);
    }
    return stringWriter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To my best of knowledge there 3 solutions.

ObjectFactory class is created automatically while jenerating jaxb from xsd/wsdl.

1. Using ObjectFactory method to create necessary object

```
marshaller.marshal(new com.myhealth.com.ObjectFactory().createSubscription(subscription), stringWriter);
```

2. Using class directly while creating marshaller

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(Subscription.class).createMarshaller();
```

3. Another approach which already being used here. I mean using package name through ObjectFactory

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(com.myhealth.com.ObjectFactory.class
            .getPackage().getName()).createMarshaller();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the context (aka package name) name in the `JAXBContext.newInstance` instantiation. It will locate the `ObjectFactory.class` located in that package, as indicated in the documentation (pt. 1)

> JAXBException - if an error was encountered while creating the
>   JAXBContext such as
>
> 1. failure to locate either ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index in the packages
> 2. an ambiguity among global elements contained in the contextPath
> 3. failure to locate a value for the context factory provider property
> 4. mixing schema derived packages from different providers on the same contextPath

```
public static String getStringFromSubscription(Subscription subscription) throws MbException {
    Marshaller marshaller;
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    try {
        marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.myhealth.com").createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration", Boolean.FALSE);
        marshaller.marshal(subscription, stringWriter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MbException(e);
    }
    return stringWriter;
}
```